# На одной странице 2 галереи, и они не работают, если одну забрать то одна галерея будет работать. Но нужно чтобы работали две

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

На одной странице 2 галереи, и они не работают, если одну забрать то одна галерея будет работать. Но нужно чтобы работали две.

Вот эта галерея: http://cleanjs.ru/articles/fotogalereya-tovarov-dlya-internet-magazina.html#comment-25

В комментариях программист объясняет почему так, но я не в состоянии это реализовать. Нужна ваша помощь.

Comment: миллион тысяч всяких готовых галерей а вы именно самую шляпную выбрали

Comment: Тут не помощь нужна, а полное изучение JS. Переписывать весь код галереи за вас ни кто не будет да и не имеет смысла вообще.